# Are SelectById, SelectByClass and SelectByName just special cases of general SelectByTag?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

2 questions in 1:
1) In all the Selenium tutorials they divide the ways of finding elements in the way like:
1. By ID
2. By CLASS
3. By NAME
4. By TAGNAME
5. By CSS Selector
6. By Link
7. By XPath

I understand there are special functions in Find.By class in Selenium for each of these, but are all of them really different ways of specifying elements in the `DOM` or `ID`, `Class` and `Name` are just a special cases of `TagNames`?
2) And in the similar way:
Are `Xpath` and `CSS` are the only actual 2 different approaches to search for elements in the `DOM` while `Name`, `Class`, `Tag`, `Text`, `LinkText` are just parameters used to specify the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**

No, a tag name is what you find in brackets:

`<tagName></tagName>`

It is a shortcut for the CSS selector `tagName`

`Name`, `ID` and `class` are all attributes of an element, they are simply shorthand for specific CSS selectors you could use. However, with this I don't mean they are executed like this behind the scenes (see Question 2 below).

- ID replaces the CSS selector `#foo`
- Name replaces the CSS selector `[name='foo']`
- Class replaces the CSS selector `.foo`

**Question 2**

Look at these source files: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/atoms/locators

It will show you how each locator finds a match. For example, the `LinkText` locator first finds all links (by tag name `a`) and then filters on the text.

Comment: I would that performance is an important issue here. Everthing depends on how the implementation is, but the it is POSSIBLE to implement faster search for ID than others types of selectors - tagname would be faster than class was well. For a pure CSS/XPATH search, one can implement a pre-search analysis for transforming it to a more specific search, e.g. if one try to search for "#my-id", it can be transformed into ID."my-id".

Comment: Locating by CSS is used by styles, so I would assume someone is spending lots of efforts to make it fast. XPATH, not so much. I (on advice of many experts on internet) try to avoid it as much as I can because it is brittle. So I assume there is less pressure to make it fast. But at least, OP has the order of preference right :-)